# Save System.Reflection.Assembly as dll file

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have some dynamic assemblies.
I would like to save them as a regular DLL file with all the metadata etc.
How can I do that please ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the `AssemblyBuilder.Save` method to save it, if you only have the resulting assembly I don't think you have enough information to save it.

Comment: Yes I just have the resulting assembly. With `ICSharpCode.Decompiler`, can I do something more ?

Comment: I would suggest to use `dnlib` for working with dynamic libraries. https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib

Comment: I have dig a bit into it and I don't see any way